# I get "undefined variable" from pydev with the code below. Can someone please tell me what's wrong

Tags: python

This is the code I've written. I'm just a beginner at python and this is part of my first practice. So, the problem is that I'm getting this "undefined variable" error for dieFace1 and dieFace2 in the last line of code here.

```
def rollDie():
    die1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
    die2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    dieFace1 = int(random.shuffle(die1))
    dieFace2 = int(random.shuffle(die2))
    dieFaceTotal = dieFace1+dieFace2
    while (userIn > pot or userIn < 0): 
       userIn = (raw_input(" Invalid bet, please enter the right bet amount"))

    print "You rolled a ", dieFace1, "and ", dieFace2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random.shuffle()` does not return anything. In your code, you should be getting something like:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Simply, just do `random.shuffle(die1)` on its own line. But this isn't needed in your case: If you want a random value from a list, use `random.choice()`:

```
dieFace1 = random.choice(die1)
```

Comment: @Patashu Depends what the OP wants, really.

Comment: dieFace1 can be any one of the numbers in the array because of the shuffle

Comment: @JeanSaint I've updated my answer. You don't need to shuffle the list, you can use `random.choice()`

Comment: @JeanSaint Yup. Good to see you got it working. By the way, I should have mentioned, you can do `random.sample(die1, 2)` Which gets two random **different** values from a list. So this saves you from having to make two lists

Answer (score 0):

Check your variables. Is it dieFace2 or dieface2?

Answer (score 0):

There were ***lots*** of problems with your code, I've corrected it and provided comments so you can learn.

```
import random
def rollDie(pot): #we need pot defined, so pas the value of the pot in
    die1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
    die2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    random.shuffle(die1) #.shuffle works in place so die1 is modified it returns None
    random.shuffle(die2) #same as above
    #ALL of the above is essentially redundant, use randint(1,6) below instead
    dieFace1 = die1[0] #this is superflous, use randint(1,6)
    dieFace2 = die2[0] #this is superflous, use randint(1,6)
    dieFaceTotal = dieFace1+dieFace2
    userIn = int(raw_input("Bet: ")) #use input for python 3
    while (userIn > pot or userIn < 0):  #pot was passed in from function call
         userIn = int(raw_input(" Invalid bet, please enter the right bet amount")) #again input for Python 3, we also need to conver to int
    return dieFace1, dieFace2

dieFace1, dieFace2 = rollDie(5) #store the values retuned in dieFace1 and dieFace2 THESE are in scope for this block level
print "You rolled a ", dieFace1, "and ", dieFace2 #ensure names are capitialised
```

Comment: Pot is a different variable from another function. Will it still be able to work? Also, is it possible to approach this in an object oriented way?

Comment: Yes, you simply need to have access to the value of pot, and then pass it into the function when you call it. It depends on the scale of your project, however if you do it will require more work and a well thought out approach.